# The permissions granted to user IIS APPPOOL\ASP.NET v4.0 are insufficient for performing this operation. (rsAccessDenied)

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, sql-server-2008-r2, ssrs-2008-r2

I am developing ASP.NET (.NET 4) application which is being hosted in IIS 7.0 of our test environment(My same pc).

I had developed few simple reports in BIDS and have alredy deployed them on Reporting Server. Now, I have included *Report Viewer* in my application so user can view those reports which are already deployed on Report Server.

If I debug the application in my local system, I can view those reports within my application. But when I deploy them in our test web server, whenever anyone (including me) try to access them it gives `rsAccessDenied error` ... the error message is,

*The permissions granted to user IIS APPPOOL\ASP.NET v4.0 are insufficient for performing this operation. (rsAccessDenied)*

Answer (score 0):

It seems the pool user account doesn't have necessary permission in the SQLReportServer.

-Create a windows user group in the server and add this user *IIS APPPOOL\ASP.NET v4.0*.

-Then make sure windows user group have a login in your database.

-Give this group admin access/ db owner rights to selected reports in your SSRS.

Refer this [Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms156034.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

This error just tell you that the user do not have permission at the reporting service. I would try to go to reporting service administration site and set content manager access to that user and check if you still get the permission error. [Check out this link as well](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/4b6e3b87-7530-4b80-893a-4b6f070d4220/rsaccessdenied)